# Comment Used To Track Changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have encountered a few issues with some code in VBA. I am trying to have the changes made to a cells on an excel sheet show up in comments on the cell the change was made to and I wish for these changes to be stored in a list so I can view them all later. I have tried lots of different pieces of code I have found to try and implement it into the code but none have worked.

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

[Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY4bA.png)

The below code is what I am currently using

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Adding As Boolean, Finding As Boolean, Subtracting As Boolean
    Dim f As Range, v

    Select Case Target.Address(True, True)
        Case "$A$4": Adding = True
        Case "$C$4": Subtracting = True
        Case "$E$4": Finding = True
        Case Else: Exit Sub
    End Select

    v = Trim(Target.Value)
    If Len(v) = 0 Then Exit Sub


    Set f = Me.Range("C8").Resize(1000, 1).Find(v, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Adding Then

        If f Is Nothing Then
            'not found: add as new row
            Set f = Me.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            f.Value = v
        End If
        f.Offset(0, 1).Value = f.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
        doDate f.Offset(0, 2)
        Target.Value = ""

    ElseIf Subtracting Then

        If f Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox v & " not found for subtraction!"
        Else
            f.Offset(0, 1).Value = f.Offset(0, 1).Value - 1
            doDate f.Offset(0, 3)
            Target.Value = ""
        End If

    Else 'finding
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            f.EntireRow.Select
            Target.Value = ""
        Else
            MsgBox v & " not found."
        End If
    End If

    If Adding Or Subtracting Then Target.Select


End Sub

Sub doDate(c As Range)
    With c
        .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
        .Value = Now
    End With
End Sub
```

I have implemented a few formulas on the worksheet but don't see any reason why it would matter in this situation since they only track quantity of items with the same unique identifier.

I also tried some code that added comments to the cells as they were changed that worked but always returned the previous cell value as blank. It is not actually added into the current code though.

```
Option Explicit 
Public preValue As Variant 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 
    Target.ClearComments 
    Target.AddComment.Text Text:="Previous Value was " & preValue & Chr(10) & "Revised " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & Chr(10) & "By " & Environ("UserName") 
End Sub 

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) 
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 
    If Target = "" Then 
        preValue = "a blank" 
    Else: preValue = Target.Value 
    End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

By and large, the code below should do what you want. I marveled at your use of A4 and C4 to express addition and subtraction. As it is, whatever you change in those two cells, apart from clearing them, will result in a quantity of 1 being added or subtracted. I would have expected that a quantity must be entered there which is processed. If the quantity is fixed at 1 the system appears too elaborate.

Anyway, here's the code. I guess you'll be able to modify it to better suit your needs.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 038

    Dim LookUp      As Variant          ' subject
    Dim Action      As Variant          ' add = 1, subtract = -1, find = 2
    Dim Fnd         As Range            ' Result of Find method
    Dim Txt         As String           ' comment text

    With Target
        If (.Row <> 4) Or (.CountLarge > 1) Then Exit Sub

        LookUp = Cells(4, "E").Value
        On Error Resume Next
        Action = Array(0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 2)(.Column)
    End With

    If Action And (LookUp <> "") Then
        ' C8 to end of column C
        With Range(Cells(8, "C"), Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
            Set Fnd = .Find(LookUp, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows)
        End With
    End If

    If Fnd Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Action
            Case -1
                MsgBox """" & LookUp & """ not found.", vbInformation, "Can't subtract"
                Action = -2
            Case 2
                MsgBox """" & LookUp & """ not found.", vbInformation, "No record"
                Action = -2
            Case Else
                Set Fnd = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                Fnd.Value = LookUp
        End Select
    End If

    With Fnd
        If Abs(Action) <> 2 Then
            With .Offset(0, 1)
                If .Comment Is Nothing Then
                    .AddComment
                Else
                    Txt = Chr(10)
                End If
                Txt = "Previous Qty = " & .Value & Chr(10) & _
                      "Revised " & Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy") & Chr(10) & _
                      "by " & Environ("UserName") & Txt
                .Comment.Text Txt, 1, False
                .Value = Val(.Value) + Action
                With .Offset(0, 2)
                    .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
                    .Value = Now
                End With
            End With
        ElseIf Action = 2 Then
            .EntireRow.Select
        End If
    End With
    If Action <> 2 Then Target.Select
End Sub
```